# using textwidth in table to make sure table width same as textwidth

Tags: tables, width

I am confused about why `\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6\textwidth} | p{0.4\textwidth}|}`  generates a table with width larger than the page `textwidth`, since `0.6+0.4` should come out to be `1.0` and so I expected the table to be same width as `textwidth`. According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout this is the Latex page layout

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but when I run the following MWE and tell `geometry` to draw the frame:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I see my table going over the texwidth, even though my 2 columns add to `100%` of the `textwidth` !

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6\textwidth} | p{0.4\textwidth}|}\hline
A&B\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the pdf

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**The question is**: What is the correct way to code this so that the columns widths add to `100%` of the `textwidth` and the table does not overflow the `textwidth`?

I am trying to make my table always to be the same as `textwidth`, and not use hardcoded width values in inches or cm as I was doing, but use fractions of the `textwidth` instead, so that if I change the style of the document or change pagesize, the table always stays as the `textwidth` in all cases.

Comment: Love the question!

Comment: @AFeldman Shouldn't you vote for it in that case? ;)

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate?

Comment: Yup, you have a very good point.  I don't think so, I just looked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculations do not take account of the width of the `|` or of the separation between the columns. You could take these into account explicitly.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-.6pt} | p{0.4\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-.6pt}|}\hline
  A&B\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: fit width]

However, it is much simpler to let a package do it for you. `tabularx` can do this job. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X | p{0.4\textwidth}|}\hline
  A&B\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y{1.2} | Y{.8}|}\hline
  A&B\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx possibilities]

In the first case, one column has specified width and the `X` expands to fill the remaining space - a bit less than `.6\textwidth`, as explained above.

In the second case, `tabularx` is asked to use two `X` columns but, rather than making them of equal size (as it would do if we used `|X|X|`, it is asked to figure out how to make one of them equal to `.4` of the available width and the other equal to `.6` of that width. It is vital that the total numbers here add up to the number of `X` columns. Here, there are 2 `X` columns and `1.2+.8` makes 2.

The code for the `Y` column specification is from the `tabularx` manual. If you use this, please see the documentation for some caveats which apply when using `X` columns of different widths. If you use one or more plain `X` columns (`|X|p{.45\textwidth}|` or `XcXXr`), these caveats don't apply. (But you should still read the manual, of course, if you use the package.)